# Scrappy xPath search the same node based on value

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

Any idea how to extract the value of "sku" based on this value, "configId": "785877"

Thanks

Scrape

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="c-quick-buy  c-product-card__buy-button"]/@data-js-component-params').extract()
```

Data extract

```
<div class="c-quick-buy  c-product-card__buy-button"

        data-js-component="quick-buy"
        data-js-component-params='{
            "product": {
                "sku": "NO225ELAQUDXANMY",
                "skuSimple": "NO225ELAQUDXANMY-799443",
                "price": "90.00",
                "configId": "785877",
                "ff": "1"
            },
            "hasSize": false
        }'
     >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how predictable is the inner json you could do something like:

```
xpath_query = '//div[contains(@data-js-component-params, \'"configId": "785877"\')]/@data-js-component-params'
js_data = response.xpath(xpath_query).extract_first() or '{}'
json.loads(js_data).get('product',{}).get('sku')
```

you could even change the the query to

```
xpath_query = '//div[re:test(@data-js-component-params, \'"configId":\s+"785877"\')]/@data-js-component-params'
```

Comment: HOLY CRAP, i have been google and searching so much but didn't found an answer, you just solved my problem. BIG thumbs up +1